# Можно ли при верстке по БЭМ использовать повторяющийся блок-обертку?

Tags: html, бэм

Можно ли в БЭМ верстке использовать блок-обертку wrapper вот таким образом? Меня смущает то, что обычно элемент, который находится в блоке вначале имеет его название, а потом через __ пишется само название элемента и если взять, например, секцию .main, то тогда блок .main__content должен называться .main__wrapper-content или же я заблуждаюсь и у меня прописано верно? Я проосто хочу, чтобы у каждой секции была обертка с определенной шириной и отступами, а когда ширина не нужна и надо сделать контент на всю ширину экрана, то создать .wrapper-fluid

```html
<section class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main__content">
      <h1 class="main__title">Заголовок</h1>
      <p class="main__text">Текст</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="features">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="features__content">
      <h1 class="features__title">Заголовок</h1>
      <p class="features__text">Текст</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="footer__content">
      <h1 class="footer__title">Заголовок</h1>
      <p class="footer__text">Текст</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вас никто не ограничивает в добавление классов, у которых будут общие стили, например - button.

А еще, вы можете использовать модификатор, например Component__button_active

Вас так же никто не ограничивает в написании другого блока. СМП НИЖЕ.

```html
<section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="footer__content content">
      <h1 class="content__title">Заголовок</h1>
      <p class="content__text">Текст</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Единственно, что не рекомендую блоку задавать внешние и внутренние отступы, но опять же так рекомендует не делать спецификация, но это не говорит о то, что если вы так сделаете, вам валидатор выкинет 10к ошибок. Нет конечно же.